# Retrieve COUNT as 0 when JOIN doesn't return value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have following tables

**Gender**

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | M           |
|  2 | F           |
+----+-------------+
```

**Department**

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID |  DepartmentName   |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Application       |
|  2 | Change Management |
|  3 | Infrastructure    |
+----+-------------------+
```

**Employee**

```
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| ID |   Name   | GenderID | StaffNumber | DepartmentID |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | Stephen  |        1 | SC001       |            1 |
|  2 | Jacob    |        1 | SC002       |            1 |
|  3 | Maria    |        2 | SC003       |            1 |
|  4 | Valerie  |        2 | SC004       |            1 |
|  5 | Herman   |        1 | SC005       |            3 |
|  6 | Trevor   |        1 | SC006       |            3 |
|  7 | Mark     |        1 | SC007       |            2 |
|  8 | Hendrick |        1 | SC008       |            2 |
+----+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

I want to find out the total number of employees grouped by Deparment & Gender. If a gender does not exist for a department, I want to still show the gender with 0 as the count.

I tried this SQL but it doesn't retrieve what I want:

```
SELECT
    e.DepartmentID,
    e.GenderID,
    COUNT(e.ID) AS TotalEmp
FROM
    Employee e
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN Gender g
            ON e.GenderID = g.ID
GROUP BY
    e.DepartmentID,
    e.GenderID
ORDER BY 
    e.DepartmentID,
    e.GenderID
```

**Current Result**

```
+--------------+----------+----------+
| DepartmentID | GenderID | TotalEmp |
+--------------+----------+----------+
|            1 |        1 |        2 |
|            1 |        2 |        2 |
|            2 |        1 |        2 |
|            3 |        1 |        2 |
+--------------+----------+----------+
```

**Expected Result**

```
+--------------+----------+----------+
| DepartmentID | GenderID | TotalEmp |
+--------------+----------+----------+
|            1 |        1 |        2 |
|            1 |        2 |        2 |
|            2 |        1 |        2 |
|            2 |        2 |        0 |
|            3 |        1 |        2 |
|            3 |        2 |        0 |
+--------------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: can you please create an sqlfiddle?

Comment: First of all: you should always use `left join`. Also, you have groupped by `e.GenderID`, change it to `g.GenderID` it may help.

Comment: Tip of today: forget about right join. Use `LEFT JOIN` instead! Same functionality, but a table order that makes sense. ("main table left join optional data", instead of "optional data right join main table".)

Comment: Prior to posting this question I tried setting up SQL Fiddle. However, SQL Fiddle always fails to work on my PC. That is why I decided to go with ASCII table instead.

Comment: See @Sanghita -s answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this:

```
   select d.DepartmentID,g.ID, COUNT(e.ID) AS TotalEmp
   from Gender g
   cross join Department d
   left join Employee e on e.genderid=g.id and e.departmentid=e.DepartmentID
   group by d.DepartmentID,g.id;
```

Comment: Do you see any Department table in the Question post?

Comment: Yes there is a department table in the question posted

Comment: @TedoG. Yep, its there.

Comment: Oh yes, it is, sorry.

Comment: Yes, this script works after minimal edit. E.g.`g.genderid` should be `g.ID` instead, etc... Thanks @Sanghita!!! Can't believe I've spent 6 hours cracking my head trying to come up with the correct script.